# why my trace plot looks like this for some parameters in Jags?

Tags: r, jags, rjags, r2jags

I am running a Hierarchical model one of the parameter's  traceplot looks like this

[image]

First question is that is it converge?

Second question is that is it because the size of the data set is too small? I just have 8 data points

third question is why these two parameters have this kind of different traceplot?

other parameter's traceplot looks good
[image]

Comment: It looks like one of your parameters is mixing REALLY slowly and only exploring the posterior in teeny tiny steps. Without the model code / data I can't really tell you why it is happening, but I'd try to reparameterize the model to improve mixing. Could it be that you have 8 data points? Maybe. Could it be something else as well? Entirely possible.

Comment: thanks mfidino could you talk more about the reparameterize the model to improve mixing? Thank you so much.

Comment: It depends greatly on the model you are using, which you've not provided any information on. For example, I have no clue what the parameter is that is not mixing well (is it a regression coefficient, an error term, or something else) nor what your priors are.